# Mysterious MS Excel error: Cannot find [..]!Local_Close_Sheet, which has been assigned to run each time myfile.xlsx is closed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-office

I receive a mysterious error each time I try to close myfile.xlsx.

> Cannot find 'X:\WINFDC[FADRVR32.XLA]FADRVR32'!Local_Close_Sheet, which has been
>   assigned to run each time myfile.xlsx is closed. Continuing could
>   cause errors. Cancel closing myfile.xlsx? Yes / No

I have removed external links and there seems to be no VBA code present.

How can I fix this?

---

I run MS Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0x) 64-bit

Comment: Hello, is there any cronjob running every time you close that file?
It's a windows error or an office (excel) error?

Comment: Can you post a print screen?

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be an error in name ranges, as described in this post:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21370755

In my situation I opened the

> Formulas > Name Manager

dialogue and deleted all names.